# integrating Birt in Laravel application

Tags: laravel, birt

Please I want to use Birt for displaying my reports in a Laravel application.

The problem is that I have followed multiple tutorials such as http://developer.actuate.com/deployment-center/integrating-birt-into-applications/birt-with-php/

The problem is when I deploy this script I get a white page!!
here is the php scipt in my laravel application:

```
    <?php
$fname = "C:/temp/test.rptdesign";
// Redirect browser
$dest = "http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=";
$dest .= urlencode( realpath( $fname ) );
header("Location: $dest" );

?>
```

My tomcat and the apache are running! I'm not getting any error but the report that i'm trying to 
generate doesn't appear.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You have a report at `C:/temp/test/rptdesign'?

Comment: the test.rptdesign is a file (report) designed by Birt tool! AS mentioned in the tutorial, this file should be in this directory! yes I have :)

Comment: if you comment our the header and echo `$dest`, do you see a fully valid path? Secondly, you should store the file within laravels storage folder or something